# Быстро дропнуть все соединения с порта

Tags: ip, debian, eth0

Вообщем в некоторых случая нужно быстро, просто взять и дропнуть весь трафик с порта или IP адреса. tcpkill начинает иметь мозги, логирует что то дропает, но это слишком долго.

ОС: дебаин.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -I INPUT -s ip -p tcp --dport port -j DROP
```

Comment: Это не то, мне нужно просто сбросить соединения.